# Using uinput.emit() Dynamically

Tags: python

I'm doing some tests with [python-uinput](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/) to simulate some key presses but I can't find a way to dynamically call `uinput.emit()`. What I mean is that I want for example to get the characters from a file and call `uinput.emit()` for each of them.

Reading the file character-by-character isn't a problem, the problem is that as far as I know `uinput` doesn't like you pass a character string or the hex code of that ASCII character. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is what getattr is for ...

```
key = "H"
my_key = getattr(uinput,"KEY_"+key)
device.emit(my_key, 1) # Press.
device.emit(my_key, 0) # Release.
```

I think should work